# Calculating JDate one off from March to November every year

Tags: java, date

I wrote a method to convert a date String into a "JDate" int (the number of days since January 1st, 1900, where 1900-01-01 counts as day 1).  However, I noticed it was not always returning the expected value; sometimes it was returning one less than the expected value.  I did some experimenting, and found that the expected value is one less from the second Monday of March through the first Sunday of November, every year.  I'm trying to figure out, why is this?

Here is my code:

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
public static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT_WITH_WEEK = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd EEE");

/**
 * Conversion method
 */
public static int getJDateFromyyyyMMdd(String yyyyMMdd) throws ParseException {
    long millisForDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse(yyyyMMdd).getTime();
    long millisFor1900 = DATE_FORMAT.parse("1900-01-01").getTime();
    long millisSince1900 = millisForDate - millisFor1900;
    return (int)TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(millisSince1900, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + 1;
}

/**
 * Method to test conversion method
 */
public static void testJDateConversion(Calendar calendar, int expectedValue) throws ParseException {
    String yyyyMMdd = DATE_FORMAT.format(calendar.getTime());
    String yyyyMMddEEE = DATE_FORMAT_WITH_WEEK.format(calendar.getTime());
    int actualValue = getJDateFromyyyyMMdd(yyyyMMdd);
    if(actualValue != expectedValue) {
        System.out.printf("%s\t\tExpected %d, Actual %d\n", yyyyMMddEEE, expectedValue, actualValue);
    }
}

/**
 * Execute
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(DATE_FORMAT.parse("1900-01-01"));
    Calendar futureDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    futureDate.setTime(DATE_FORMAT.parse("2020-12-31"));
    for(int expectedJDate = 1; calendar.before(futureDate); expectedJDate++) {
        testJDateConversion(calendar, expectedJDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
}
```

Here is some of what gets printed out:

```
2013-11-02 Sat      Expected 41579, Actual 41578
2013-11-03 Sun      Expected 41580, Actual 41579
2014-03-10 Mon      Expected 41707, Actual 41706
2014-03-11 Tue      Expected 41708, Actual 41707

...

2014-11-01 Sat      Expected 41943, Actual 41942
2014-11-02 Sun      Expected 41944, Actual 41943
2015-03-09 Mon      Expected 42071, Actual 42070
2015-03-10 Tue      Expected 42072, Actual 42071

...

2015-10-31 Sat      Expected 42307, Actual 42306
2015-11-01 Sun      Expected 42308, Actual 42307
2016-03-14 Mon      Expected 42442, Actual 42441
2016-03-15 Tue      Expected 42443, Actual 42442
```

Any ideas as to what's causing this unusual behavior?

Comment: BTW… What is a `JDate`? In what context/library/platform is this used?

Comment: A "JDate" is a concept of representing the date as a number of days since a start date (which often ends up being 1/1/1900, but in some conventions starts at year "0" (which is awkward as there was no year "0", but I digress...)  ).  As for the context, I can't provide a lot of detail because it's client work for a corporation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that your problems are caused by DST (Daylight Saving Time). Summer time is active between about March to October/November and it differs by region.

For example in my case this code:

```
    System.out.println(DATE_FORMAT.parse("2015-03-01"));
    DATE_FORMAT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println(DATE_FORMAT.parse("2015-03-01"));
```

Produces this output:

```
Sun Mar 01 00:00:00 CET 2015
Sun Mar 01 01:00:00 CET 2015
```

You could try to set the TimeZone to UTC.

(I worked on such DST issues with multiple timezones several years ago, but my memory is not too fresh and I have to dig a few things out again.)

UPDATE:

I tried a quick test for your code with setting a common TimeZone for everything and it now should give the results you expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    DATE_FORMAT.setTimeZone(utc);
    DATE_FORMAT_WITH_WEEK.setTimeZone(utc);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
    calendar.setTime(DATE_FORMAT.parse("1900-01-01"));
    Calendar futureDate = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
    futureDate.setTime(DATE_FORMAT.parse("2020-12-31"));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was it.  Should have realized DST would cause issues, especially since I was calculating milliseconds.  This work around is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30356171/642706) is correct.

By the way, if `1900-01-01` is day # 1, then your [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) is actually the day before, `1899-12-31`.

## java.time

If you can use Java 8 or later, this work is *much* easier. Use the new [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Unlike java.util.Date/.Calendar, the java.time package offers the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class to represent date-only without any time-of-day or time zone. So no Daylight Saving Time or other anomalies to resolve.

```
LocalDate epoch = LocalDate.of( 1900 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ).minusDays( 1 );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyyMMdd" );

long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( epoch , LocalDate.parse( "20131102" , formatter ) );
String output = epoch.plusDays( days ).format( formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "From epoch of " + epoch + " adding " + days + " days = " + output );
```

When run.

```
From epoch of 1899-12-31 adding 41579 days = 20131102
```

## Joda-Time

If you cannot move to Java 8, use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library for this work. It too offers a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate epoch = new LocalDate( 1900 , DateTimeConstants.JANUARY , 1 ).minusDays( 1 );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.basicDate();

int days = Days.daysBetween( epoch , formatter.parseLocalDate( "20131102" ) ).getDays();
String output = epoch.plusDays( days ).toString( formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "From epoch of " + epoch + " adding " + days + " days = " + output );
```

When run.

```
From epoch of 1899-12-31 adding 41579 days = 20131102
```

Comment: Great stuff!  I would totally do it this way if I was allowed to use Java 8 or Joda Time.  Unfortunately, the constraints on Client work don't always make sense.